# ElasticSearch: Allow only local requests

Tags: elasticsearch

How can allow only local requests for elasticsearch? 
So command like:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings'
```

can only be running on localhost and request like:

```
curl -XGET 'http://mydomain.com:9200/twitter/_settings'
```

would get rejected?

Because, from what i see, elasticsearch allows it by default.

**EDIT:**

According to http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/network.html
you can manage `bind_host` parameter to allow hosts. And by default, it is set to `anyLocalAddress`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

For elasticsearch prior to v2.0.0, if you want both http transport and internal elasticsearch transport to listen only on localhost simply add the following line to `elasticsearch.yml` file.

```
network.host: "127.0.0.1"
```

If you want only http transport to listen on localhost add the following line instead.

```
http.host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Starting from v2.0 elasticsearch is listening only on localhost by default. So, no additional configuration is needed.

Comment: Actually, you should be combine both answers.

Comment: @user469652 you only need to set network.host. It achieves the same thing as http.host (and more).

Comment: For those searching for the inverse of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222093/elasticsearch-listen-to-multiple-ips

Answer (score 6):

If your final goal is to deny any requests from outside the host machine, the most reliable way would be to modify the host's [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) so that it denies any incoming requests to the service ports used by ElasticSearch (9200-9300).

If the end goal is to make sure that everyone refers to the service using an exclusive DNS, you're better off achieving this with an HTTP server that can proxy requests such as HTTPd or nginx.

Comment: yeah, that was my first idea, but i was wondering if there isnt any configuration for elastic. Thanks.

Comment: @smolnar - elasticsearch may not be able to help you directly, it isn't a webserver/firewall. You would need to run it behind a webserver like nginx to have more control. At least that's what I did.

Comment: Just verify that your iptable rules are loaded on reboot. I've had a server hacked because I forgot to set +x on the script to update the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I use this parameter:

http.host: "127.0.0.1"

This parameter not accept http requests for external request.