# How disable remote access in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When running a elasticsearch server.
We can access `www.example.com:9200`

But i want block remote access only allow local access.

How to setting?

Comment: Could you please accept/upvote the answer you got if it was useful, or provide feedback otherwise? Anything to add?

Comment: Do you even firewall :-)

Answer (score 19):

Instead of disabling whole HTTP protocol by changing `http.enabled` in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` settings (because some of your APIs can use the HTTP endpoint which was my case), you can just set `network.host: localhost` in the same file.

This will make your `:9200` HTTP access to be available only from your local machine/server.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503455/elasticsearch-allow-only-local-requests

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch allows you to disable the http endpoint just setting `http.enabled` to false in the settings. It also allows to have a local node which will only be reachable in the same jvm. On the other hand you are asking how to allow only local access to the rest endpoint, which is different and require the use of additional tools.

In fact, it's not a good idea to expose elasticsearch to the internet. I would use a proxy like apache or Nginx to limit the access to it and open for instance only some of the available endpoints, but that's needed only if you have external users that want to send messages directly to elasticsearch. Usually that's not the case. Or if you just want to deny access to it for all external users, because it's for instance only your website or application that needs access to it, just use a firewall and setup a proper rule to close the 9200 port.

Answer (score 2):

You should set http.host to "127.0.0.1". This way you can access http on port 9200 from host itself, however not from outside. This also allows you to put a proxy which listens on some other port and filters and passes the requests selectively to elasticsearch node on localhost:9200.

For example, you may want to reject the request for shutdown, do a basic authentication using nginx and then pass all query requests to elasticsearch cluster url at http://localhost:9200.

This doesn't involve firewall.