# elasticsearch listen to multiple ips

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to listen to multiple host adresses so that I can listen to localhost requests AND private IP requests?

something like:

```
network.host: "127.0.0.1", "192.168.1.4"
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is the global listener, do you mean 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In fact yes it is.
Use the JSON notation.

This is what I used in my configuration:
`network.bind_host: ["yourhost", "localhost"]`
and
`network.publish_host: yourhost`
as you don't want to send multicast packets on the loopback interface.

Comment: It's yaml, no json :)

Comment: yaml is superset of json :)  (and i did not know that either for the longest time)

Comment: YAML is a subset (not superset) of JSON. And only since YAML 1.2 (http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)

Comment: @Martin, Tom is right. See section 1.3: "YAML can therefore be viewed as a natural superset of JSON, offering improved human readability and a more complete information model. This is also the case in practice; every JSON file is also a valid YAML file." The statement in the first section isn't very well put and easy to misunderstand.

Comment: Alas, this does not work with 2.1.1. My configuration has `network.bind_host: [ "192.168.0.1", "127.0.0.1" ]` but the log states `publish_address {192.168.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {127.0.0.2:9200}, {[::1]:9200}` and elastic does **NOT** listen on the external interface.

Answer (score 14):

I tested the given solution and it did not work. I concluded that Elastic cannot listen on *specific* interfaces using `network.bind_host` in the configuration.

However you **can** tell elastic to listen on *all* interfaces by specifying:

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: <your external address>
```

This will make sure one address is published (to the cluster) but all addresses are accessible. Tested and verified with Elastic 2.1.1.

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks! I'd added another interface to my ES hosts, but the hosts couldn't reach each other on those.  After a restart the cluster wouldn't come up warnings like `completed handshake with [{es-3}{1.2.3.4}{2.3.4.5}] at [1.2.3.4:9300] but followup connection to [2.3.4.5:9300] failed`. Using `publish_host` let the cluster talk amongst itself to the correct addresses, and still listened on the other interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

```
network.host: [  _site_ , _local_ , _global_ ]
```

- _local_ : Any loopback addresses
- _site_ : Any local (internal) addresses
- _global_: Any external IP

you can instead specify network interface name like `[ _eth0_ , _lo_ ]`