# ElasticSearch port 9200 open to everyone. Is it wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, symfony, elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch running with a PHP-Symfony app, and a mysql DB.
Everything is working fine, but I just have one concern, not sure if this is critical or not. Hope community will help.

If I'm trying to access my server IP on port 9200 like this:

> http://[serverIP]:9200

I have a JSON / Object output:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Cutthroat",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.3",
    "build_hash" : "NA",
    "build_timestamp" : "NA",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Therefore my questions are: Is it a problem everyone can access this URL? Is it a security breach? Please provide resources to make your point, if possible.

If yes, how to solve this? I tried to block access to everyone on `port 9200`, and only authorize `localhost` with `iptables`, but Elasticsearch then stopped working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch: Allow only local requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503455/elasticsearch-allow-only-local-requests)

Comment: Leaving any database exposed to the public internet is asking for trouble. These services aren't designed to be resistant to brute force attacks like HTTP servers typically are. Most HTTP servers can be tweaked to throttle hostile connections, plus they're also rarely a source of vulnerabilities in comparison to databases.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You can use Shield https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/introduction.html

Comment: Configure Elasticsearch to only allow connections from certain IP Addresses. See imotov's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503455/elasticsearch-allow-only-local-requests?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @DivijSehgal working! Thanks!

Comment: @yofisim great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is here: [ElasticSearch: Allow only local requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503455/elasticsearch-allow-only-local-requests?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Check @imotov answer.

Thanks to @DivijSehgal for pointing out the solution